# Onclick does not work using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have worked with Django and Bootstrap, and I have a problem with onclick attribute. When I click on a button, it does not show me nothing. Here are the HTML:

```
{% extends 'base_profile.html' %}

{% block profile %}

<br />
    <div id="content">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="container">
    <div class="fb-profile">
        <img id='background_picture' align="left" class="fb-image-lg" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/ad/38/bd/ad38bd348826054d3fd5e940950b1124.jpg" alt="Profile image example"/>
        {% load staticfiles %}
        <img id='profile_picture' align="left" class="fb-image-profile thumbnail" src="{% static 'media/{{path}}' %}" alt="media/{{path}}"/> 
        <!-- 200 x 200 -->
        <div class="fb-profile-text">
            <a href="/profile" id="full_name">{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</a>
            <div id="wrap">
            <p>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/profile">My profile</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="/fallowers">Fallowers</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="/fallowing">Fallowing</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation">
                    <button id="compose" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Compose Twitt
                    </button> </li>
                </ul>
            </p>
            <p>{{ user_profile.moto }}</p>
            {% for twitt in all_twitters reversed %}
            <hr>
            <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left media-middle">
                    <a href="#">
                    {% load staticfiles %}
                        <img class="media-object" src="{% static 'twittapp/images/logo_profile.png' %}" alt="Some picture">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="">{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</a></h4>
                        {{ twitt.content }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>

            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="deleteTwitt();" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete</a>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Comment</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> See the comments</a>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
    </div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Compose Twitt</h4>
      </div>

      <form action="/profile/compose/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-body">
            <textarea style="resize:none" class="form-control" rows="3" cols="20" name="twitt_content" id="textarea"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button id="save_twitt" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Twitt</button>
        </div>
        <p id="left_chars">sdks</p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock profile %}
```

Here is a function located in the external js file:

```
function deleteTwitt(){
    $.post('/delete', {twitt_id: '{{ twitt.id }}'});
};
```

Comment: put a log or an alert with in your function to make sure you getting into the function.

Comment: I've already do this, and it does not go into a function.

Comment: of course it is getting into the function. I tried it check here http://jsfiddle.net/9y79nbhn/

Comment: Ok, but it does not work with me .. ;( ..

Comment: post all your code so we can see it then ( the whole page not sinppets like you posted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you have embedded external js file using script tag in current page and if it is not then please embed it and check. If file is embedded then just change following in your HTML code

```
<a href="#" onclick="deleteTwitt();" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete</a>
```

Here I just removed "javascript:void(0)" from href of anchor tag. Still if it's does not work then let me know.